# why can't this Lua function using a self ":" be marked "local" without getting "'(' expected near ':'"

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Why can't this Lua function using a self ":" be marked "local" without getting:

> '(' expected near ':'

That is, in the code below things work.  But why can't I make the "scene:createScene" function local (as I get the above-mentioned error when trying).

I note the listener functions need to be made local else I have struck cross-scene issues at times in storyboard.  These can be marked local and work fine.

```
SceneBase = {}
function SceneBase:new()
  local scene = Storyboard.newScene()

  local function returnButtonTouch_Listener (event)
    -- code here
  end

  function scene:createScene( event )   -- WHY CAN'T THIS BE LOCAL???
    -- code here
  end

  return scene
end
return SceneBase
```

That is why can't the function line read:

```
  local function scene:createScene( event )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function scene:createScene(event) ... end
```

Is syntax sugar for:

```
scene.createScene = function(self, event) ... end
```

Which is syntax sugar for:

```
scene["createScene"] = function(self, event) ... end
```

You want to do:

```
local scene["createScene"] = function(self, event) ... end
```

Which makes no sense.

---

Another way of putting it: `local` is a qualifier for a variable which makes it local rather than global. What variable would you be qualifying with `local function scene:createScene( event )`?

`createScene` is not a variable, it's a key in the table `scene`.

---

Actually, that's a bit misleading. When you say:

```
foo = 10
```

Without qualification, `foo` becomes global, which is to say it's stored in the global state like this:

```
_G.foo = 10;
```

Which of course means the same as this:

```
_G["foo"] = 10;
```

When you use the keyword `local`, it doesn't get stored in a table, it ends up stored in a VM register, which is both faster and has more tightly constrained scope.

When you write either of these:

```
function foo.bar() end
function foo:bar() end
```

You are *explicitly storing the function value in a table* (`foo`). Those statements are exactly equivalent to these, respectively:

```
foo["bar"] = function() end
foo["bar"] = function(self) end
```

---

> I note the listener functions need to be made local

What do you mean by that? In Lua, a function is a function is a function. It's just another value, like a string or number. Whether it's stored in a global, table, local, or not stored at all is irrelevant.

```
local foo = print
_G["zap"] = foo
doh = zap
t = { zip = doh }
t.zip("Hello, World") -- Hello, World

assert(print == foo
    and zap == foo
    and zap == doh
    and t.zip == doh)
```

Here we pass the `print` function around. It's all the same function, and as long as we have a reference to it we can call it.

I don't know Corona, but I'm guessing that event handlers are not specified by naming convention of locals. You need to register it as an event handler. For instance, according to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5Oz72MO4JI) a Button object has an `onEvent` field which is set to the handler for that button.

Comment: great response - thanks very much for this - makes sense now.  re listeners, I had some problems in that multiple files we "inheriting" from the base class I think, and as the listeners were global well something got screwed here.  When I marked them as local the bug I had disappeared.

Comment: A beautifully clear explanation of why not.  But, is there still any way to have a "local" function that wants to reference self? ie, something sort of like a java private, or a C local function?  Is there a better way? PIL chapter 16 isn't super clear